# Single node Artifactory OSS installation with Docker failing

Tags: docker, artifactory

I am trying to install single node Artifactory OSS installation with Docker by referring https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/install-artifactory-single-node-with-docker

Container does not start and container log shows below error. I tried adding node details in system.yaml and also checking permissions. However it does not help. Could you please help on with this.

```
[root@test-node ~]# docker run --name artifactory -v /opt/jfrog//artifactory/var/:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
Preparing to run Artifactory in Docker
Running as uid=1030(artifactory) gid=1030(artifactory) groups=1030(artifactory)
Dockerfile for this image can found inside the container.
To view the Dockerfile: 'cat /docker/artifactory-oss/Dockerfile.artifactory'.
Copying Artifactory bootstrap files
2023-06-19T10:27:30.503Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:607       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.node.id (test-node) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2023-06-19T10:27:30.549Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:607       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.node.ip (10.230.248.177) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2023-06-19T10:27:30.849Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:607       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.extraJavaOpts (__sensitive_key_hidden___) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
2023-06-19T10:27:30.896Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:607       ] [main] - Resolved .shared.extraJavaOpts (__sensitive_key_hidden___) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
```

systems.yaml is as below

```
[root@test-node ~]# cat $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
## @formatter:off
## JFROG ARTIFACTORY SYSTEM CONFIGURATION FILE
## HOW TO USE: comment-out any field and keep the correct yaml indentation by deleting only the leading '#' character.
configVersion: 1

## NOTE: JFROG_HOME is a place holder for the JFrog root directory containing the deployed product, the home directory for all JFrog products.
## Replace JFROG_HOME with the real path! For example, in RPM install, JFROG_HOME=/opt/jfrog

## NOTE: Sensitive information such as passwords and join key are encrypted on first read.
## NOTE: The provided commented key and value is the default.

## SHARED CONFIGURATIONS
## A shared section for keys across all services in this config
shared:
  ## Java 17 distribution to use
  #javaHome: "JFROG_HOME/artifactory/app/third-party/java"

  ## Extra Java options to pass to the JVM. These values add to or override the defaults.
  extraJavaOpts: "-Xms512m -Xmx2g"

  ## Security Configuration
  security:
    ## Join key value for joining the cluster (takes precedence over 'joinKeyFile')
    #joinKey: "<Your joinKey>"

    ## Join key file location
    #joinKeyFile: "<For example: JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/security/join.key>"

    ## Master key file location
    ## Generated by the product on first startup if not provided
    #masterKeyFile: "<For example: JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/security/master.key>"

    ## Maximum time to wait for key files (master.key and join.key)
    #bootstrapKeysReadTimeoutSecs: 120

  ## Node Settings
  node:
    ## A unique id to identify this node.
    ## Default auto generated at startup.
    id: "test-node"

    ## Default auto resolved by startup script
    ip: 10.230.248.177

    ## Sets this node as primary in HA installation
    #primary: true

    ## Sets this node as part of HA installation
    #haEnabled: true

  ## Database Configuration
  database:
    ## One of mysql, oracle, mssql, postgresql, mariadb
    ## Default Embedded derby

    ## Example for postgresql
    #type: postgresql
    #driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    #url: "jdbc:postgresql://<your db url, for example: localhost:5432>/artifactory"
    #username: artifactory
    #password: password
```

Comment: Which of the output lines do you feel is an error? What commands/output do you have showing the container did not start?

Comment: @BMitch - Unfortunately logs does not show any error. However container get exited.

`[root@test-node ~]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                   COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                       PORTS     NAMES
7ab5cbf27a7b   releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest   "/entrypoint-artifac…"   20 seconds ago   Exited (99) 18 seconds ago             artifactory
[root@test-node ~]# `

Comment: @Shailesh did you manage to fix the problem?